# Opening a PDF on a web form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I am looking for the simplest way to open a PDF when a link or button is clicked. This is on a web page and for example will say . Any advice on how to store this PDF also so it can be generated and displayed would be greatly appreciated as it is a very large file with massive amount of content. I have tried doing it on the button click event but failed miserable as have never opened a external file before.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.. Do you mean to say you have a file in some directory and want ti display it on your website?

Comment: Yes it is save in a directory, I want to open up the PDF in a new web page tab when I click on a link on my web page through a href tag.

Comment: Try searching for "ASP.NET download file link". It's been asked a bazillion times before.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as. To open the pdf is new tab you want to use `_blank` value for the `target` attribute

```
<a href="PathToYourPdfDocument" target="_blank" >Message Here</a>
```

Comment: <a href="C:\Users\nfallon\Documents\Aasleagh Lodge.pdf" target="Aasleagh Lodge" style="text-decoration:none;">CLICK HERE FOR MORE INFO!</a>    I tried this but when I click on the link nothing happens.

Comment: @Frank because you can't use physical file paths for `href` or `src`. You need to use an absolute or relative URL.